# replace pattern in a string (if exists)

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

i would like to remove a pattern from a string (if the pattern occurs). It looks like: "_20180301_010000_c", where numbers indicates the timestamp and 'c' is additional identifier.

Example:

```
 val text: String = "file-client-and-reports_20190512_010012_c.csv"
 val text2 = text.replaceAll("[0-9]","").replaceAll("___c","")
 // incr_claim-party-contact-number___c.dat - result after first replaceAll
 // incr_claim-party-contact-number.dat - result after second replaceAll - ok!
```

I used replaceAll method twice, but looking for the general rule.

Comment: do you want to remove also all `_` characters?

Comment: Yes, i want toremowe: _ between numbers, one _ after and one _ before numbers, 'c' before file extension. _ in the first part of string should remain unchanged.

Comment: So what's the exact ouput you'd like for `file-client-and-reports_20190512_010012_c.csv`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:_[0-9]+)+_c(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

Or, if there can be no `_<digits>` before `_c` use this variation:

```
(?:_[0-9]+)*_c(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W4oPwZ/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A_%5B0-9%5D%2B)%2B_c(%3F%3D%5C.%5B%5E.%5D%2B%24)):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:_[0-9]+)+` - one or more repetitions of a `_` and 1+ digits sequence (if there can be no `_<digits>` before `_c`, replace the last `+` with `*` to match *0 or more* repetitions)
- `_c` - a `_c` substring
- `(?=\.[^.]+$)` - that is immediately followed with `.` and 1+ chars other than `.` to the end of the string

Scala:

```
val text: String = "file-client-and-reports_20190512_010012_c.csv"
val text2 = text.replaceAll("""(?:_[0-9]+)+_c(?=\.[^.]+$)""","")
println(text2)
// => file-client-and-reports.csv
```

See [online demo](https://rextester.com/VTH64108)